# Error using PHP in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: php, azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to connect to a service bus queue in Microsoft Azure using PHP, using the following code found on the Azure guide:

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Queue\QueueRestProxy;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Exceptions\ServiceException;
    use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Queue\Models\CreateMessageOptions;
    $connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="name";AccountKey=key";
    // Create queue REST proxy.
    $queueClient = QueueRestProxy::createQueueService($connectionString);
    try{
        // Create message.
        $builder = new ServicesBuilder();
        $queueClient->createMessage("cmps297r1", "Hello World!");
    }
    catch(ServiceException $e){
        // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
        // Error codes and messages are here:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179446.aspx
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
    }
?>
```

However, when I run it, I get this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 4 passed to MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\ServiceRestProxy::__construct() must be an instance of MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\Serialization\ISerializer, array given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/297R/vendor/microsoft/azure-storage/src/Queue/QueueRestProxy.php on line 110 and defined in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/297R/vendor/microsoft/azure-storage/src/Common/Internal/ServiceRestProxy.php on line 77

Comment: Could you post the full source code? From your code I don't see whether you have created queue or not yet. Note that the code below belongs to Azure Storage Queue, not Service Bus Queue.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted looks fine to me (except that you didn't include `use` statement for `ServicesBuilder` class which would cause an "*Class not found*" error).

And as @Thuan Ng mentioned the code above belongs to Azure Storage Queue, not Service Bus Queue. You need to refer to this documentation [How to use Service Bus queues with PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-php-how-to-use-queues) if you are using Azure Service Bus.

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is an old Post but you are trying to create a storage queue and not a service bus queue